# Memory Error while reading the string

Tags: c, pointers

```
// Gurucharan Sharma
// 24 February 2015
//
// Program to create a stack that can
// push and pop (char *) or strings and
// elements of other data types.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define TODO //TODO

typedef struct {
    void *elems;
    int elemSize;
    int logLength;
    int allocLength;
} stack;

void stackNew(stack*, int);
void stackPush(stack*, void *elemAddr);
void stackPop(stack*, void *elemAddr);
void stackDispose(stack*);

int main() {
    const char *friends[] = {"Al", "Bob", "Carl"};
    char *name = {'\0'};
    int i, j;

    // Creating the new stack.
    stack stringStack;
    stackNew(&stringStack, sizeof(char *));

    // Pushing strings onto the stack.
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        char *copy = _strdup(friends[i]);
        stackPush(&stringStack, &copy);
    }

    // Poping the stack elements.
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        stackPop(&stringStack, &name);
        printf("%s\n", name);         // error is generated on this statement
        free(name);
    }

    // Disposing off the stack memory.
    stackDispose(&stringStack);

    _getch();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void stackNew(stack *stringStack, int elemSize) {
    stringStack -> elemSize = elemSize;
    stringStack -> logLength = 0;
    stringStack -> allocLength = 3;
    stringStack -> elems = malloc((stringStack -> allocLength) * elemSize);
    assert((stringStack -> elems) != NULL);
}

void stackPush(stack *stringStack, void *elemAddr) {
    void *target = (char *) (stringStack -> elems) + 
        (stringStack -> logLength) * (stringStack -> elemSize);
    memcpy(target, elemAddr, stringStack -> elemSize);
    (stringStack -> logLength)++;
}

void stackPop(stack *stringStack, void *elemAddr) {
    void *source = (char *) stringStack -> elems + 
        (stringStack -> logLength) * (stringStack -> elemSize);
    memcpy(elemAddr, source, (stringStack -> elemSize));
    (stringStack -> logLength)--;
}

void stackDispose(stack *stringStack) {
    free(stringStack);
}
```

This program was written for GCC Visual studio 2013. If running in some other compiler, please replace _getch() with getch(), or if you are running the program on UNIX system, remove the  header file and getch() entirely.

This program results in the error **Error while reading characters of strings**. I have tried all sorts of solutions but to no avail. Please help.

The TODO section is for growing the size of the stack->elems once the allocatedLength gets equal to the logicalLength.

Comment: `stackPush()` and `stackPop()` function signatures do not match with their definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void stackPop(stack *stringStack, void *elemAddr) {
    void *source = (char *) stringStack -> elems + 
        (stringStack -> logLength - 1) * (stringStack -> elemSize);
    memcpy(elemAddr, source, (stringStack -> elemSize));
    (stringStack -> logLength)--;
}
```

I just made changes in the stackPop() function and the error disappeared!

Notice the statement:

```
void *source = (char *) stringStack -> elems + (stringStack -> logLength - 1) * (stringStack -> elemSize);
```

I just used stringStack -> (logLength - 1) instead of stringStack -> logLength for obvious reasons that I failed to notice before!

Answer (score 1):

You `free` what `name` points to *inside a loop*, which begins with a static allocation, and then never gets re-allocated.

Comment: Firstly, I tried declaring the 'name' inside the loop but the error still existed. Secondly, I tried to free the name outside the loop but still the error was there.

Comment: You never allocate it; why would you ever free it?

Comment: I tried removing the free statement but it still throws the error. I just can't figure out why the error is showing up. It is a run-time error!

Comment: How much space did you set aside to store a string in `name`?

Comment: Well I haven't any and to be frank I don't know how to. I have tried all I could! Please tell me!

Comment: You learned about how to `free` things but not allocate them?

Comment: Well I tried using malloc to allocate the memory that name would require to store the string but error still persists!

Answer (score 0):

You pass `name` into the `stackPop` function where it is used as the target of `memcpy`. However, it has not been allocated correctly, it is too small.